# Multiples instance of Producer/Consumer with Monitor in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, java.util.concurrent

I'm building a webcrawler to download files from websites. I've a producer (the link fetcher) and a consumer (the downloader).

They both can be summarized as followed :

```
//Fetcher implements Runnable
public void run(){
  while(String link = getLinkFromDatabase != null){
     String htmlContent = HTTPrequest.getHTMLtoString(link);
     ArrayList<String> links = HTTPrequest.getUrlsFromString(htmlContent); //Custom Parser/Extractor
     ArrayList<String> files = HTTPrequest.getFilesFromString(htmlContent);//Custom Parser/Extractor
     String SqlQueryAddLinks = "INSERT IGNORE DUPLICATE INTO [...]"; //Insert query for Links with unique key : sha256 of the url.
     String SqlQUeryAddFiles = "INSERT IGNORE DUPLICATE INTO [...]"; //Insert query for Files with unique key : sha256 of the url.
     Queries.sqlExec(SqlQueryAddLinks);
     int RowAffected = Queries.sqlExec(SqlQueryAddFiles);
     Queries.archiveLink(link);
     Monitor.append(RowAffected);
  }
}

//Downloader implements Runnable
public void run(){
  while(String link = getFileFromeDatabase != null){
     //You don't care of steps here I just download the file
     if(fileDownloaded){
        Queries.archiveFile(link);
        Monitor.take();
     }
  }
}
```

Now i'm trying to synch both thread to assure that links cannot be too old. To do so I'm using Monitor (as described in Operating Systems : Internals and design principles wrote by William Stallings)

```
public class Monitor{
   int N = 10;
   int count;
   Condition notfull, notempty;

   public Monitor(){
      count = 0;
   }

   public void append(int nbr) throws InterruptedException{
      if(count >= N){
         notfull.wait();
      }
      count+=nbr;
      notempty.signal();
   }

   public void take() throws InterruptedException{
      if(count == 0){
         notempty.wait();
      }
      count--;
      notfull.signal();
   }
```

Now the thing is that I want to launch multiples couples of fetcher and downloader sync by a monitor. Do I need to create a new Monitors object and add a Monitor into the class of my Downloader and Fetcher or is there a better way ? The book isn't talking about multiples Producer/Consumer and is using the function `parbegin(producer, consumer);` in C++ (I presume it's C++).

Comment: There's queue abstraction, tailored for multi-threaded apps, see JDK `BlockingQueue` and its descendants. It's more robust version of your `Monitor`. If you want several pairs of producer-consumer, the simplest way is to have one such queue per pair (although, there are other options, which depend on how exactly you want to link your producers with your consumers).

Comment: Isn't `BlockingQueue` slower than mycode since I don't care about storing elements but just checking the number i've got ? I didn't knew about it anyway thank you.

Comment: Your code seem to fetch `link` twice, once in each runnable, although via different methods. If link is the same, you can use queue: store link in db and place it into queue afterwards for downloader. Downloader will call `queue.take()` and won't need to fetch it from DB (if I got code purpose correctly).

Comment: I might have not make my code clear. The first runnable extract from table_url (wich are url to explore but not file to download) and feed the database in url to explore and file to download (their url). The second runnable extract from table_file wich store only file url to download.
The problem is that I've to fetch it at least twice since I need to make sure a url doesn't already exist in the database when I add it.

Comment: Ok, but better solution against data duplication is to make DB-level unique index which will prevent URL duplication. You can still use `BlockingQueue` to pass `rowAffected` to consumer.

Comment: It's already what I do for the DB. Thank you for your advises.

Answer (score 0):

Just by eyeballing, this code doesn't compile for many reasons and has guaranteed runtime failures.

a) you try to call a static method take/append but they are not static.

b) you try to have 2 Condition objects but you have no reentrant lock.

c) you don't even lock/unlock the reentrant lock behind the condition before waiting/notifying

d) you use Condition.wait() instead of the .await().

e) you are using Condition.signal() instead of the .signalAll()